# How do I check a question has been answered in TrakCare?

Tags: caching, intersystems, objectscript

First a bit of background.  I am not a programmer.  I'm a nurse who also happens to be a bit of a geek and would love to be a programmer.
I've recently started working in our Digital team at the hospital I work at and we have a contract with, and use InterSystems Trakcare.  As part of this we create Questionnaires for our clinicians to use and in these questionnaires we can add what InterSystems refer to as "Expressions", which I'm told are written in cache script.
I have a questionnaire that I'd like an expression that checks if a question has been answered before writing a message, but I have no idea how to do that.

The only expressions I've written so far have been to write a message based on a score value, and to do those I had to look at Questionnaires created by Intersystems and basically copy their code.

There is a questionnaire that has the following expression, that seems to retrieve data from questions within it's questionnaire but I'm beggared if I can work it out or get it working in my questionnaire.  So I'm hoping someone can talk me through this code and explain what each line does.

```
Do ##Class(websys.Component).GetComponentMessages(.t,"questionnaire.QTC4AT.Edit")
set score=obj.QUESScore
set sr1=$get(t("Q48"),">= 4: Possible delirium +/- cognitive impairment")
set sr2=$get(t("Q49"),"1-3: Possible cognitive impairment")
set sr3=$get(t("Q50"),"0: Delirium or severe cognitive impairment unlikely (but delirium still possible if [4] information incomplete)")
set srx=""
if (score'="") set srx="No valid score"
if ((score'="") && (score>=4)) set srx=sr1
if ((score'="") && (score>=1) && (score<=3)) set srx=sr2
if ((score'="") && (score=0)) set srx=sr3
write srx
```

I know you probably have better ways to spend your time but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe TrakCare-specific portal at https://client.intersystems.com/ would be a better place to ask such questions because it's more about configuring your system rather than general programming. For TrakCare version T2020 and later, we have a new code table "Questionnaire Scores" which you can use instead of custom expressions, and it will work in both TCUI and MEUI. The code below will not work on MEUI because we don't support custom expressions there.

Back to your question though,

```
; Load item captions for questionnaire QTC4AT
Do ##Class(websys.Component).GetComponentMessages(.t,"questionnaire.QTC4AT.Edit")
; Get current score
set score=obj.QUESScore
; Get caption of Q48 into variable sr1; if it's not defined use provided caption
set sr1=$get(t("Q48"),">= 4: Possible delirium +/- cognitive impairment")
; etc etc for sr2 and sr3
set sr2=$get(t("Q49"),"1-3: Possible cognitive impairment")
set sr3=$get(t("Q50"),"0: Delirium or severe cognitive impairment unlikely (but delirium still possible if [4] information incomplete)")
; set resulting variable srx to an empty string
set srx=""
; if we got a score, set resulting variable srx to "No valid score"
if (score'="") set srx="No valid score"
; set resulting variable srx to different captions we got above based on score value
if ((score'="") && (score>=4)) set srx=sr1
if ((score'="") && (score>=1) && (score<=3)) set srx=sr2
if ((score'="") && (score=0)) set srx=sr3
; output resulting caption
write srx
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, your comments make perfect sense to me.  I have signed up for an account at client.intersystems.com with my NHS email address but am awaiting "verification".  Until then there is no content visible to me.

What I'm trying to achieve with an expression is to check that a question has been answered or not before evaluating the rest of the expression, and the $get commands looked hopeful.  
We upgraded to T2020 late last year and I can't see any "Questionnaire Scores" code table there, all I see is Site Specific "Questionnaire Score Conversion"